# Getting method information of a WCF REST service in client application

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest

How can I get the information about WCF REST service method details on client side

For Ex: I have a method

**string GetDetails(string fname)**

then my client application will show what is the return type of the function(**string** in this case), parameters required (**fname**) along with the name of the function(**GetDetails**).

You can say I want to create a WCF Test Client application for WCF REST service.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want meta information of service method.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher If I'll get the desired info from meta, then yes

Comment: You can use Reflections or make your own class that stores method information and return that class back.

Comment: I want to make a generic application...In which if I'll give a reference to my service I ll be able to get all the methods and their details. I think I have to use WSDL for that service.